# Can I use zend translate, date and cache as standalone class in my project?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm going to use Zend framework but just some tool of Zend like translate, date and cache. Can I use it as standalone class? My project has it own structure and I don't want use the whole Zend fw. If yes, which files should I include in my project? Is there a docs for using each Zend fw tool as standalone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And remember, to use various Zend Framework components in another project, you just need to have the `Zend` library somewhere on your `include_path`. Copying the whole thing may seem overkill to use one component, but it's only disk space. Having those files there doesn't affect performance unless they are called upon. And this way, you don't have to sweat the dependencies, like `Zend_Exception` and its various component-specific subclasses.

So, for example, if you have a folder `myapp/lib` to contain your external libraries, you simply make sure that your include path contains that `lib` folder and copy the `Zend` folder into it as `myapp/lib/Zend`.

Then to use a component like `Zend_Translate`, all you have to do is something like the following:

```
require_once 'Zend/Translate.php';
$options = array(
    // your options here
);
$translate = new Zend_Translate($options);
```

With some kind of autloading mechanism in place, you can avoid even the `require_once` call. Setting up autoloading is as easy as putting the following in some kind of common/bootstrap file:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

Then any classes that follow the [PEAR 1-class-1-file naming convention](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php) can be loaded without explicitly adding any require/include statements.

If disk-space really is a concern and you really don't want the whole `Zend` library, then you could investigate a packageizer, like [Jani Hartikainen's Packageizer](http://github.com/jhartikainen/packageizer).

Answer (score 2):

As an answer i could say Yes of course.

for example if u want to use Zend_Translate copy Translate.php and Translate folder to your library directory.

some times inside a class some other classes have been used. u have to copy them too. i find them by reading raised errors. ;)

Comment: Dont forget grab Exception.php... Its required for pretty much every component.