# how to determine dependent library in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I completed my very first project in zend framework!! Thanks to stackoverflow community!!

While uploading files, i didn't know how to include zend library so i uploaded the whole library in the **/library** folder of my project base.

Is there a way to determine which library is used and which in not (like compilation that automatically copies dependent files to library folder  *incase webhost does not provide zend library* ..)? i would be awfully bad to manually add each file and test weather the particular library is added or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836792/can-i-use-zend-translate-date-and-cache-as-standalone-class-in-my-project/3838157#3838157) essentially says don't worry about including the whole library. I usually put the whole library in the project `library` folder, just like you did.

But if it is truly problematic to include the whole library, you could take a look at [Jani Hartikainen's Packageizer](https://github.com/jhartikainen/packageizer) which, at least in a previous form that I played with, allowed you to specify the components you needed and it would chase the dependencies and wrap them in a neat little package.

Answer (score 1):

Disk space is cheap. Just have the entire ./Zend library directory (and maybe ./ZendX, if you are using that) into your own library directory where it will used. With autoloading, nothing that isn't being used will take up any significant memory. taking even 5 minutes trying to figure out is time (and therefore money) that is more usefully spent writing code.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it would be worthwhile/reliable to subclass the autoloader for this and have it optionally log each class it loads during site operation (sort of how Zend_Translate can log untranslated strings).

You could have it turned off normally but in your testing environment you would turn it on (via your application.ini), and have it build your dependency list while your unit tests are running.