# Want to use Zend_translate outside the Zend framework?

Tags: php, multilingual, zend-translate

i m creating a website with multilingual features. and i have search and found the zend_translate is the best way to translating the text. but i have started my website with simple php(no framework) and completed many modules. **but now i want to use translator in my site which translate the php texts and the text come from the database(mysql)**

i can use gettext() but i have no rights to install the gettext() on my live server so i have choose zend_translate. so can anybody help me to use zend_translate with using the zend framework and without copying the whole zend library files. or give me some another way.

Thanks.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836792/can-i-use-zend-translate-date-and-cache-as-standalone-class-in-my-project

Comment: hi thanks for reply i have checked and integrate the zend_translate in my site. but can you tell me how zend_translate will translate the text comes from database. i need this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pull just Zend_Translate unless you decide to modify its code, by using Zend_Translate you will have to get Zend_Exception, Zend_Registry (not sure about this), Zend_Cache (if you want caching) and thats it I think.

Copy the needed code to you project, with the appropriate adapter you want to use, and then just create instance of Zend_Translate as following

```
$translator = new Zend_Translate(array(
    'adapter' => 'gettext',
    'content' => '/my/path/source-de.mo',
    'locale'  => 'de'
));
```

Then somewhere in your code do

```
echo $translator->_('Welcome back'), ' ', $username;
```

To add more languages do something like:

```
$translator->addTranslation(
array(
    'content' => '/path/to/translation/fr-source.mo',
    'locale'  => 'fr'
));
```

And to output with french locale write:

```
$translator->setLocale('fr');
echo $translator->_('Welcome back'), ' ', $username;
```

For more information please see http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html
Good luck!